# Possessive adjective / pronoun

Tags: possessive-pronouns, possessive-adjectives

Why do we write yours sincerely instead of your sincerely. Here I think before sincerely we need a possessive adjective and 'your' is doing this job well.

Answer (score 2):

"Yours sincerely" is short for "I am yours sincerely". "Sincerely" is always an adverb. Because there is no noun, "yours" is used instead of "your".

---

(If signing off of letters like this seems weird, it was definitely a lot weirder [in the past](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/464899/191178).)